# How to convert a list of tuples into list of dictionaries with plus values?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples, e.g: `list_of_tuples = [('company_name', 56, 'green'), ('other_company', 43, 'blue')]`

I have to convert this into a list of dictionaries in python. The key should be the company_name, and the values should be in a list, and I also have to add more values, like: `[{'company_name' : [56, 'green', 'more_value'}, {'other_company' : [43, 'blue', 'more_value'}`]

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post it.

Comment: Why do you need a list of dictionaries with only one key instead of a dictionary with multiple keys?

Comment: @Holt Just guessing but there are formats that use lists of dictionaries to pass data around like JSON

Comment: Also, where are these other values coming from? Eg, are they in a list that's synchronised with `list_of_tuples`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension like so

```
>>> [{i[0] : list(i[1:])} for i in list_of_tuples]
[{'company_name': [56, 'green']}, {'other_company': [43, 'blue']}]
```